# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WpOrg\Requests\Hooks' not found

Tags: php, hook, fatal-error

I've been getting the same error message the last few days...makes me think it has something to do with the update?

I've tried: disabling plugins, and downloading/removing themes and reinstalling twenty twenty-one.

I'm new to Wordpress, therefore have no backup, and at a complete loss here. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WpOrg\Requests\Hooks' not found in /home/sites/17a/3/36b2a5154b/practicalpathways/wp-includes/class-wp-http-requests-hooks.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /home/sites/17a/3/36b2a5154b/practicalpathways/wp-settings.php(249): require() #1 /home/sites/17a/3/36b2a5154b/practicalpathways/wp-config.php(92): require_once('/home/sites/17a...') #2 /home/sites/17a/3/36b2a5154b/practicalpathways/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/sites/17a...') #3 /home/sites/17a/3/36b2a5154b/practicalpathways/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/sites/17a...') #4 /home/sites/17a/3/36b2a5154b/practicalpathways/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/sites/17a...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/sites/17a/3/36b2a5154b/practicalpathways/wp-includes/class-wp-http-requests-hooks.php on line 18

Notice: Function is_embed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/sites/17a/3/36b2a5154b/practicalpathways/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865

Notice: Function is_search was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/sites/17a/3/36b2a5154b/practicalpathways/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you are using an old version of WordPress or after updating WP Core something goes wrong and there are some files missing.

In those cases, the best is to download the latest WordPress version, then uploading to your server and replacing the files and folder. Notice after downloading the WordPress ZIP file the structure could be a bit different so maybe you need to extract it on your PC first, then navigate to the folder and compress the files and folder of WordPress again to have a smooth Upload and Extract on the site, otherwise could be possible you need to cut/move after extract on the site.

If you feel comfortable with SSH you can use it to do the same:

1. Navigate to the root of your site for example cd /var/www/html/
2. Then execute: wp core download --version=6.2 --force

You should change to 6.2 for the latest stable version of WordPress.

I hope this helps you.